# Cant redirect folder exluding one subfolder - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am having problems writing some redirect rules. I want all the pages inside the "/es" folder to be redirected to my homepage but excluding the pages in /es/empresa that need to redirect to mydomain.com/nosotros/. I have written this code but it is not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/empresa/($|/)
RewriteRule / http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use these 2 redirect rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^es/empresa(/.*)?$ /nosotros$1 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteRule ^es(/.*)?$ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I am sorry but I am very new to this..Where should I enter the URLs for the redirect? thx!

Comment: Once you have above code in root .htaccess you can then enter `http://example.com/es/` in your browser for testing.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I explain myself badly. I need that all the pages on /empresa/ to redirect to example.com/nosotros.html....

Comment: Sorry it is all unclear now. You will need to click on edit link below your question and clarify your requirements properly.

Comment: Ok, I just did it. Thanks again :)